# In a 2D array of JButtons, how to change lines?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

I am trying to create a 2D array of buttons but the buttons I created are all in the same line. I can change lines in 2D arrays of int and float by using System.out.println(). What should I so for buttons? (line 67 to 75)
As well, I don't know how to create actionListeners for buttons in a loop. Should I create a method for acctionLisener? Do they share the same action listener?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;

public class Hanoi {

    private JFrame frame;
    JButton[][] buttons= new JButton[3][3];

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Hanoi window = new Hanoi();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Hanoi() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 901, 696);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panelone = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panelone, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelone.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panelone = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panelone.columnWidths = new int[]{0};
        gbl_panelone.rowHeights = new int[]{0};
        gbl_panelone.columnWeights = new double[]{Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panelone.rowWeights = new double[]{Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panelone.setLayout(gbl_panelone);

        JPanel paneltwo = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(paneltwo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        paneltwo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel lblFunHanoiTower = new JLabel("Fun Hanoi Tower");
        lblFunHanoiTower.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lblFunHanoiTower.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
        lblFunHanoiTower.setFont(new Font("Viner Hand ITC", Font.PLAIN, 36));
        paneltwo.add(lblFunHanoiTower);

        //JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];

        for(int row = 0; row < buttons.length ; row++) {
            for(int col= 0; col < buttons[0].length ;col++) {
                buttons[row][col] = new JButton(String.valueOf((row+3)+(col*3)));
                buttons[row][col].setFont(new Font("Tempus Sans ITC", Font.BOLD, 16));
                buttons[row][col].setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
                buttons[row][col].setSize(66, 66);
                panelone.add(buttons[row][col]);
                }
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: What is the class of variable `panelone`? Is it `javax.swing.JPanel`? If it is, what layout does it use?

Comment: Yes. This is the code:JPanel panelone = new JPanel();
  frame.getContentPane().add(panelone, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  panelone.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

Comment: I did not change the initialized layout. Which layout should I use?

Comment: @WeilanTao `JPanel` gives itself a `FlowLayout` by default. You probably want a either a `GridLayout` or a `GridBagLayout` instead.  If you're not familiar with layout managers, read all about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. Buttons are still in the same line.

Comment: *I tried. It doesn't work.* - you are not using the GridBagLayout correctly (you don't specify any constraints when you add the buttons to the panel). Don't use the GridBagLayout. Use the `GridLayout`. It is simpler to use. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for a working example. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use GridbagLayout` for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than modify your code, I have provided an example of `GridLayout`.
`GridLayout` divides the area of the `JPanel` into a grid, i.e. a table of rows and columns, where each "cell" in the grid can contain one component and each cell has the same size. Here is a complete, compilable and runnable example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Hanoi implements Runnable {

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createGridPanel() {

        // Number of rows will be calculated depending on total number
        // of components added but each row will contain no more than
        // three components.
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(0, 3);

        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(gridLayout);
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                int number = (row + 3) + (col * 3);
                String text = String.valueOf(number);
                JButton button = new JButton(text);
                gridPanel.add(button);
            }
        }
        return gridPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hanoi");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createGridPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hanoi instance = new Hanoi();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(instance);
    }
}
```

And here is a screen capture of the running application.
(Note that I am using JDK 12 on Windows 10.)

[image: Hanoi]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid layout, i change your original code (as you can see below). I recommend to use some designer for the gui, it more easy and clean. Net beans have a nice grafic interface builder.

```
public class Hanoi {

private JFrame frame;
JButton[][] buttons= new JButton[3][3];

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Hanoi window = new Hanoi();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Hanoi() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 901, 696);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panelone = new JPanel();
    panelone.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelone);
    panelone.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    /*GridBagLayout gbl_panelone = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panelone.columnWidths = new int[]{0};
    gbl_panelone.rowHeights = new int[]{0};
    gbl_panelone.columnWeights = new double[]{Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_panelone.rowWeights = new double[]{Double.MIN_VALUE};*/
   // panelone.setLayout(gbl_panelone);

    JPanel paneltwo = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(paneltwo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    paneltwo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JLabel lblFunHanoiTower = new JLabel("Fun Hanoi Tower");
    lblFunHanoiTower.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    lblFunHanoiTower.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    lblFunHanoiTower.setFont(new Font("Viner Hand ITC", Font.PLAIN, 36));
    paneltwo.add(lblFunHanoiTower);

    //JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];

    for(int row = 0; row < buttons.length ; row++) {
        for(int col= 0; col < buttons[0].length ;col++) {
            buttons[row][col] = new JButton(String.valueOf((row+3)+(col*3)));
            buttons[row][col].setFont(new Font("Tempus Sans ITC", Font.BOLD, 16));
            buttons[row][col].setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
            buttons[row][col].setSize(66, 66);
            panelone.add(buttons[row][col]);
            }
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Don't use an IDE to generate the code. The code is messy and is not portable if you ever move to another IDE.

Comment: any way if you try the code that i made for you to get the expected result, the use of netbeans it's only a suggestion

Comment: _I recommend to use some designer for the gui, it more easy and clean_ I think beginners should not use wizards that generate code for them but should write the code themselves because that way they discover and learn what code they need to write instead of having it written for them. Once they learn and understand the code required to write a _Swing_ application and if the wizard generates the same code as they would write anyway, using a wizard can save time.